# Unpause SKScene after UIAlertView barges in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, skscene

Does anyone else know how to solve this?

When a SKScene is running, it is forced into pause state if an UIAlertView (or similar object) barges in.

When I'm the one who fired the alert it's easy to unpause the scene, I just handle the delegate methods.

However, when it is fired without my hand in it, such as a connection error report or user-set alarm, I can't seem to be able to detect the view was dismissed in order to call the play method to resume my SKScene presentation.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: You mean your app is replaced by another? Try the UIApplicationDelegate messages such as applicationDidEnterForeground and so on

Comment: Not quite, I meant as in when an alarm fires up while you're in an app; an UIAlertView (or similar object) pops up and pauses the app, then when dismissed unpauses everything other than SKScenes.
But will try your suggestion, sounds promising.